# PHPUnit+Selenium: 'displayed()' isn't working on popover element

Tags: javascript, php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

In my PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase test case, I try to open a bootstrap popover element (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) and then click a link inside.

I manage to open it, but then I can't click the link because PHPUnit considers that it's still hidden. I use the waitUntil function but it timeouts, although the element is in fact visible (I can see the popover opened when I run the test case).

My code:

```
// open popover
$this->byXPath("//something")->click();

// wait
$this->waitUntil(function() {
    return $this->byId("myId")->displayed() ? true : null;
}, 2000);

// click on link (never reached, the previous function timeouts)
$this->byId("myId")->click();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could the popup be an `<iframe>` perhaps?

Comment: No, it's only a `<div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are getting the error, I believe the problem is with your markup / js. Just checked the below with the latest libraries, works fine (url navigation doesn't work from the popover for some reason):

```
class Test extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('chrome');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('');
    }

    public function test()
    {
        $this->url('http://jsfiddle.net/ianbytchek/0adyuhkg/embedded/result/');
        $this->frame($this->byXPath('//*[@id="result"]/iframe'));

        // open popover
        $this->byXPath("//button")->click();

        // wait
        $this->waitUntil(function () {
            return $this->byId("myId")->displayed();
        }, 2000);

        // click on link (never reached, the previous function timeouts)
        $this->byId("myId")->click();

        sleep(10);
    }
}
```

When the link gets clicked, the button changes the style, check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ianbytchek/0adyuhkg/).

Comment: you're right, the problem was not here: I use a hidden `<div>` to store the popover content and I give its html to the `popover()` function: `content: function () { return $(this).find('.hiddendiv').html();}`. Of course, my XPath found the id that was in the hidden `div`. Solved, thank you.